# how to use identity in dot net core preview 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, dotnet-cli

how to use identity in dot net core preview-2. 
i want to develop system with database first approach.i show many videos and tutorials, but all are in dot net core(1.1).
I tried with create new project with individual identity from visual studio 2017. 
please help me.

Comment: Since you are not mentioning if you using nightlies or not: Read the announcements for https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262 , it's for the coming RTM Version or any post-preview2 nightly builds (at least that what it has been tagt for)